# Continue Increment after firing off() or unbind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to complete a increment and decrement thru minus and plus sign.

I achieved the increment but there's a condition that if it reaches 20, it will stop. So to do that i used off('click') to stop the click function. It stops however when I click the minus and click the plus again it wont increment no more.  Maybe because the handler was removed.

I tried unbind() but its the same or even set return false; or preventDefault();

https://jsfiddle.net/ryuchix/nakgac59/18/

```
var skill = 0;

$(function() { // on page load
  $('.plus').on('click', function(){
    skill++;
   var input = $('.inputplus').val(skill);
   $('figcaption').html($('.inputplus').val() +'/20');
   if($('.inputplus').val() == 20) {
   $(this).unbind('click');
   }
  });
  $('.minus').on('click', function(){
    skill--;
    $('figcaption').text(skill +'/20');
  });
}); 


<div id="container">
<figure class="skill1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign minus"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign plus"></span>
          <figcaption>0/20</figcaption>
          <input type="hidden" class="inputplus" min="0" max="20">

      </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unbinding the click handler, just do a check before incrementing skill.  You may also want to disable the plus sign when it hits 20 and re-enable it when below 20.

i.e.

```
$('.plus').on('click', function(){
 if (skill < 20) {
  skill++;
 }
 if (skill >= 20) {
   $('.plus').prop('disabled', true);
 }
 var input = $('.inputplus').val(skill);
 $('figcaption').html($('.inputplus').val() +'/20');
});
$('.minus').on('click', function () {
 //your code...
 //re-enable plus after any minus click, since it will always be 
 //bringing skill to lower than 20
 $('.plus').prop('disabled', false);
})
```